# MySQL Get Different Records Bewteen Two Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to show  "Scheduled vs Actual" report which shows difference between the two tables in MySQL database that hold attendance for school.

I have two tables called Booking and Attendance.

Data stored in the tables are as below:

Booking

```
Id Student   Date     IsAbsent
1  John      20160216    1 //NO
2  Bob       20160217    1 //NO
3  Zara      20160218    1 //NO
```

Attendance

```
Id Student    Date     IsAbsent
1  John       20160216    0 //YES
2  Bob        20160217    0 //YES
3  Mary       20160217    1 //NO
```

Basically I want to show the output as

```
**Id | Student | Day_1 | Day_2  |  Day_3**
 ==== ========= ======  =======  ======
   1 | John    |ABSENT | NULL   | NULL 
   2 | Bob     |NULL   |ABSENT  | NULL
   3 | Mary    |NULL   |NEW     | NULL
   4 | Zara    |DELETED|NULL    | NULL
```

**ABSENT** John in Booking's table is Marked as 1(False) but in Attendance table he is marked as 0(YES) so I want to show as 'ABSENT'

**NEW** Mary has an entry only in Attendance table but NOT IN Booking table.

**DELETED** Zara was originally booked and is in Booking table but is not in Attendance table.

I have created [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92fee/47) of schema and the query I am using but it always return nulls.

My SQL Query is like below..

```
 SELECT * FROM 
((SELECT
  a.Student as student,
   MAX( case
       when a.DropDate='20160216' && a.IsAbsent=0 && s.IsAbsent=1 then 'Absent'
       when (select count(*) from attendance where DropDate='20160216')=0 && (select count(*) from staging where DropDate='20160216')>0 then 'DELETED Booking'
       when (select count(*) from attendance where DropDate='20160216')>0 && (select count(*) from staging where DropDate='20160216')=0 then 'New Booking' 
       else ' ' end ) as 'day_1',
  MAX( case 
       when a.DropDate='20160217' && a.IsAbsent=0 && s.IsAbsent=1 then 'Absent'
       when (select count(*) from attendance where DropDate='20160217')=0 && (select count(*) from staging where DropDate='20160217')>0 then 'DELETED Booking'
       when (select count(*) from attendance where DropDate='20160217')>0 && (select count(*) from staging where DropDate='20160217')=0 then 'New Booking' 
       else ' '  end ) as 'day_2',
  MAX( case 
       when a.DropDate='20160218' && a.IsAbsent=0 && s.IsAbsent=1 then 'Absent'
       when (select count(*) from attendance where DropDate='20160218')=0 && (select count(*) from staging where DropDate='20160218')>0 then 'DELETED Booking'
       when (select count(*) from attendance where DropDate='20160218')>0 && (select count(*) from staging where DropDate='20160218')=0 then 'DELETED Booking' 
       else ' '  end ) as 'day_3'
FROM Attendance a LEFT JOIN Booking s on a.Student=s.Student
WHERE a.DropDate IN ('20160216','20160217','20160218')
   AND  NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM Booking AS p
        WHERE p.Student = a.Student
          AND p.IsAbsent = a.IsAbsent
          AND p.DropDate = a.DropDate
      )
)
UNION 
(SELECT
  t.Student as student,
  MAX( case
       when t.DropDate='20160216' && a.IsAbsent=0 && t.IsAbsent=1 then 'Absent'
       when (select count(*) from attendance where DropDate='20160216')=0 && (select count(*) from staging where DropDate='20160216')>0 then 'DELETED Booking'
       when (select count(*) from attendance where DropDate='20160216')>0 && (select count(*) from staging where DropDate='20160216')=0 then 'New Booking' 
       else ' ' end ) as 'day_1',
  MAX( case 
       when a.DropDate='20160217' && a.IsAbsent=0 && t.IsAbsent=1 then 'Absent'
       when (select count(*) from attendance where DropDate='20160217')=0 && (select count(*) from staging where DropDate='20160217')>0 then 'DELETED Booking'
       when (select count(*) from attendance where DropDate='20160217')>0 && (select count(*) from staging where DropDate='20160217')=0 then 'New Booking' 
       else ' '  end ) as 'day_2',
  MAX( case 
       when a.DropDate='20160218' && a.IsAbsent=0 && t.IsAbsent=1 then 'Absent'
       when (select count(*) from attendance where DropDate='20160218')=0 && (select count(*) from staging where DropDate='20160218')>0 then 'DELETED Booking'
       when (select count(*) from attendance where DropDate='20160218')>0 && (select count(*) from staging where DropDate='20160218')=0 then 'DELETED Booking' 
       else ' '  end ) as 'day_3'
FROM Booking t LEFT JOIN attendance a on t.Student=a.Student
WHERE t.DropDate IN ('20160216','20160217','20160218')
  AND  NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM Attendance AS u
        WHERE u.Student = t.Student
          AND u.IsAbsent = t.IsAbsent
          AND u.DropDate = t.DropDate
      )
)) tbl
ORDER BY  student
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is interesting I have a similar question in the pipeline am following up on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im' not sure you can output an inline layout within a MySQL query, unless you  make a procedure...
I don't know if this is ok for you as it has a slightly different layout, but it works :

```
(select s.Student,
       s.ClassRoom,
       s.DropDate,
       if(s.IsAbsent=1&&a.IsAbsent=0,'ABSENT','PRESENT')
from Staging s inner join Attendance a on a.Student = s.Student and a.ClassRoom = s.ClassRoom and a.DropDate = s.DropDate)
UNION ALL
(Select s.Student,
       s.ClassRoom,
       s.DropDate,
       'DELETED'
from Staging s left join Attendance a on a.Student = s.Student and a.ClassRoom = s.ClassRoom and a.DropDate = s.DropDate
where a.Student is null)
UNION ALL
(Select a.Student,
       a.ClassRoom,
       a.DropDate,
       'NEW'
from Staging s right join Attendance a on a.Student = s.Student and a.ClassRoom = s.ClassRoom and a.DropDate = s.DropDate
where s.Student is null)
order by Student, DropDate;
```

Comment: Thank you @Stan exactly the results I am trying to achieve but I need to show the dates horizontally :-(

Comment: dynamic pivoting seem appropriate here. I found an [interesting tutorial](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using your query and inserting the result set into a a temporary table and then doing a dynamic pivot on it. As this is only once off so I have hardcoded the dates but in real world maybe a different logic:

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AttendanceDiff (
   student int(5) NOT NULL
  ,classroom int(5) NOT NULL 
  ,dropdate varchar(12)NOT NULL
  ,status varchar (12
)

SELECT
  student,
  case(DropDate)
  when '20160222'
  then CONCAT(status)
  else ' '  end  as 'day_1',
  case(DropDate)
  when '20160223'
  then CONCAT(status)
  else ' '  end  as 'day_2'
FROM AttendanceDiff

DROP TABLE AttendanceDiff